# How to handle missing PST hour in Java

Tags: java, timezone

I have a webapp that is to be deployed on server having Pacific TimeZone setting. My app is capable of handling PST<->PDT date conversions in calculations but i am facing issue handling missing hour/Invalid Time as described below.

Invalid Time – Between 02:00 AM to 03:00 AM on second Sunday in March due to forward auto-adjustment of clock, this time does not exist in Pacific Time Zone.

So whenever date like 10-Mar-2013 02:00:00 is entered system automatically converts it into 10-Mar-2013 03:00:00. I understood this is happening because this time is actually does not exist in Pacific timezone.

But as per requirement server timezone can not be changed (for eg. GMT) and still need to capture above time (10-Mar-2013 02:00:00). Additionally server auto-adjutment clock settings also can not be changed so i have to do application code change to support above.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Adding code for more clarification:

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("ddMMyy HH:mm:ss");
//sdf.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT"));
Date date = sdf.parse("100313 02:00:00");
Date date1 = sdf.parse("100313 03:00:00");
System.out.println(sdf.format(date));
System.out.println(sdf.format(date1));

Output:
100313 03:00:00
100313 03:00:00

If i uncomment commented line then output:
100313 02:00:00
100313 03:00:00
```

Comment: Why? You can pass "10-Mar-2013 02:00:00" as GMT time before entering into the system or pass as a String parameter and convert to Date object after it entered?

Comment: i am receiving date from hibernate native query to don't have option there pass it as GMT.

Comment: You say this is a web app?  Are you running this in a JSP page or something?  Where do the dates originate, and what do they represent? You say the user is entering them in - do you mean in a web browser?  Can you use JavaScript there?  Are they representing the user's local time zone that might be different than the server time zone, and do you care?

Answer (score 0):

Regardless of the time zone setting of the computer, you should always be able to get the current UTC time.  Java abstracts this from the OS details, so any time the documentation says you are getting a UTC value (such as milliseconds from 1/1/1970 UTC) then it is accurate.  There is no such thing as missing or ambiguous time in UTC.

The reason that it is recommended your servers are set to UTC time zone has to do with the way the system bios clock is synchronized with the operating system's clock.  Microsoft Windows operating systems keep the bios on local time and adjust it as necessary, while Linux and Macintosh keep the bios permanently on UTC.  Because of this, on Windows systems, there is a remote possibility that the clock is read incorrectly if the adjustment didn't work for some reason.  [More on this issue here](http://www.cl.cam.ac.uk/~mgk25/mswish/ut-rtc.html).

If your application is converting dates entered to values that only make sense in the computer's local time zone, then you have projected that time zone on to your users.  For desktop applications, this is probably correct because the user is running the code on their own computer.  For web applications (and other server-side code), this is certainly the wrong thing to do, because it is possible for the client to be in a different time zone than the server.

Please update your question to show the specific code from your application that is causing the problem you described.  We can then point you at the specific changes you need to make so your application behaves correctly.

Comment: "There is no such thing as missing or ambiguous time in UTC."  Except maybe leap seconds.  :D

Comment: "If your application is converting dates entered to values that only make sense in the computer's local time zone, then you have projected that time zone on to your users."  Date values make sense in any time zone because they are completely independent of TZ; the TZ is only used when converting to/from that value from/to a human-readable format. If the server assumes a TZ when converting an entered date, and the entered date was not expressed in that TZ, than the parsed value is wrong. The app will behave correctly if you ever get date values from any other source (like the system time).

Comment: @AlvinThompson - I was speaking about dates/times in general.  You are correct that the Java `Date` class represents UTC and all values are acceptable.  Good point about leap seconds, but they can almost always be ignored.

Comment: **CORRECTION:** The app will **not** behave correctly if you ever get date values from any other source (like the system time).

Comment: i have added code in the post for more clarification on the issue, please note that the code is executed under system set to PST timezone.